# how to obtain all subclasses of a class in php

Tags: php, inheritance, subclass

Is it possible to get all subclasses of given class in php?

Comment: You mean like "hey, PHP, what subclasses are out there for class MyBaseClass"? Probably not, because they may live in files that aren't loaded.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
function getSubclassesOf($parent) {
    $result = array();
    foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) {
        if (is_subclass_of($class, $parent))
            $result[] = $class;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Coincidentally, this implementation is exactly [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436159/how-to-get-all-subclasses/436204#436204) given in the question linked to by Vadim.

Comment: Yes, it's just necessary to keep in mind it will only work if the files defining these classes are already (auto)loaded. Great code though.

Answer (score 4):

Using PHP 7.4:

```
$children = array_filter(get_declared_classes(), fn($class) => is_subclass_of($class, MyClass::class));
```

Comment: Looks like PHP 8.0 for me. But still upvoting because of the clean oneliner alternative

Answer (score -2):

```
function getClassNames(string $className): array
{
    $ref = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $parentRef = $ref->getParentClass();

    return array_unique(array_merge(
        [$className],
        $ref->getInterfaceNames(),
        $ref->getTraitNames(),
        $parentRef ?getClassNames($parentRef->getName()) : []
    ));
}
```

Comment: The request is for the child classes, not the parent class.