# Finding subclasses automatically in PHP

Tags: php, subclass

What I am trying to do is find all subclasses that extends a certain base class.

This is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/436204/1369417, except that the classes will *not* be loaded at the time that the function is called.

Essentially, what I am hoping to do is:

1. Include all PHP files in a directory.
2. Test if each include introduced a new subclass of the base class.

But I want to do the include in an isolated PHP environment such that I am protected from any errors and warnings that may be introduced by including the PHP file.

Here is a small example:

**BaseClass.php**

```
<?php
abstract class BaseClass {}
?>
```

**FirstSubclass.php**

```
<?php
class FirstSubclass extends BaseClass {}
?>
```

**Blah.php**

```
<?php
class SecondSubclass extends BaseClass {}
?>
```

**badcode.php**

```
<?php
adfgklmdflgksdfge@#4234t0q3
?>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php
require('BaseClass.php');
print_r(find_subclasses(BaseClass));
?>
```

**Expected output**

```
Array (
    [FirstSubclass.php] => FirstSubclass,
    [Blah.php] => SecondSubclass,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

use this function

```
function getSubclassesOf($parent) {
    $result = array();
    foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) {
        if (is_subclass_of($class, $parent))
            $result[] = $class;
    }
}
```

from [how to obtain all subclasses of a class in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470008/how-to-obtain-all-subclasses-of-a-class-in-php)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but in order to use this, I would first need to "include" the PHPs files in which the classes are located, which I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: @JoshuaSpence in order to use the classes we have to include that PHP files. Because otherwise we don't know from where this classes comes. :)

Comment: I am aware of this... but using your code in my above example would produce the following error: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '@' in /home/joshua/Dropbox/Desktop/test/badcode.php on line 2". This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: spawn a quick `php -l` over the file contents first, then assuming they are valid php, include them.

Comment: @JoshuaSpence Can you explain why you have created `badcode.php`. Its having error.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar it's probably either homework, or a job interview question. :/

Comment: @RibaldEddie. Neither. It's for a utility I am writing for my team where many people write subclasses and I cannot control the quality of the code that they write :)

Comment: @JoshuaSpence ok.  Well php -l will do it,

Comment: `php -l` will not protect you if `badcode.php` is included from another file (that passes the -l syntax check).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably to read the files instead of including them, and then do some simple parsing yourself to look for class definitions and inheritance. It's then fairly easy to build an inheritance hierarchy that you can query for sub classes and base classes.